# web: how to zoom into a grid item and keep the item centralized in the viewport

Tags: javascript, css, zooming

So I have a grid where I want to zoom in a grid item

what am I using? `transform: scale()` to zoom the grid container, and `element.scrollIntoView()` to move the grid item to the center of the viewport

What is the issue?

css transform: `scale()` focus on the centre of the element.
This causes the zoom effect made by scale() navigate to the right of the grid because it is the centre of the grid container and I want to zoom the grid item only keeping it focused on the centre of the viewport.
I have a grid who has many items and it is bigger than the viewport so when I do `scale()` the viewport moves to the centre of the grid container instead of doing zoom into the current viewport centre

my current work: https://codepen.io/mejingjard/pen/pVPmmb

**how to test:**

uncomment line `44` on the JS panel, with that line commented out the only thing that is happening is navigate to the clicked item but no zoom in, this line applies the `scale()` and `translate()` together using `matrix()` but it is moving the viewport to the wrong place, I think the values passed to the translate might be wrong, but I've been trying for days and decided to ask for help

[image: visual-explanation]

Comment: Calculate the position of your element relative to the overall dimensions of the element being zoomed and set the `transform-origin` of the element being zoomed (using `%`) in the middle of the element you want to zoom on. You also want to translate it so the element being zoomed on comes in the center of the screen.

Comment: would you mind to try that in the codepen link I attached to the question? I don't understand exactly what you mean

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu or at least give me more details, the getBoundingClientRect() is the thing to get the relative element position? // did you look at the code?

Comment: Scaling the entire library is both confusing (UX wise) and complex (code-wise; because you're using `scrollIntoView()` which is experimental and doesn't seem to have a callback param). I've added an answer which simply scales the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting a `transform:scale(X)` on the `.selected` item seems to do the trick:

```css
.selected {
  transform: scale(1.7);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

And here's the simplified Javascript i used:

```js
function onBookClick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  unSelect();
  event.target.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "center",
    inline: "center"
  });
  $(event.target).addClass('selected');
}

function unSelect() {
  $('.books__item').removeClass('selected')
}

$('.books').on('click', '.books__item:not(.selected)', onBookClick);
$('.books').on('click', '.selected', unSelect);
```

Updated [pen](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/wjeodR).

Comment: thanks! I appreciate your help, but I'm really willing to achieve a zoom effect there and will keep my journey till there

Comment: The problem is `transform` **does not actually change the item in DOM**. It just renders it elsewhere/differently. I belive `sIV` scrolls to the actual position of the element in DOM, not to where `scale()` on parent throws it. However, the way to do it is to set the `tranform-origin` of the parent in the center of the scrolled child. [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) and [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) should be used, but I'm not sure what they return before `scrollIntoView()` and after it.